# MySQL InnoDB constraint does not work

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key, constraint

I stumble upon strange behavior with innoDB constraint, and cannot find cause of it.
I have tables with data.
Below listed their structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `contents` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `fields` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nameUNIQUE` (`name`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `dataTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `value_UNIQUE` (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `content_data` (
  `content_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`,`field_id`,`data_id`),
  KEY `fk_content_data_2_idx` (`field_id`),
  KEY `fk_content_data_3_idx` (`data_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_content_data_1` FOREIGN KEY (`content_id`) REFERENCES `contents` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_content_data_2` FOREIGN KEY (`field_id`) REFERENCES `fields` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_content_data_3` FOREIGN KEY (`data_id`) REFERENCES `dataTable` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, let's execute two queries:
First query:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `dataTable` where id=21318;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

We got empty set and that is ok since `dataTable` in fact has no any row with id=21318
Second query:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `content_data` where data_id=21318;
+------------+----------+---------+
| content_id | field_id | data_id |
+------------+----------+---------+
|        552 |       35 |   21318 |
+------------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, last query give us result with data_id=21318. WTF!

---

How to explain this situation?
Why constraint does not work?
Any idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to the value of `foreign_key_checks` variable. Try the following statement, and check the value:

```
mysql> show variables like 'foreign_key_checks';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
```

Comment: It is enough if the setting was disabled when the data were inserted/modified, it might be enabled now.

Comment: Link to the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks The Note is particularly relevant: "Setting foreign_key_checks to 1 does not trigger a scan of the existing table data. Therefore, rows added to the table while foreign_key_checks = 0 will not be verified for consistency."